# I just started learning XSL, and need to do some exercises

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the input1.xml file, create an XSL file that will transform it to the format of output1.xml.

the input1.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Trips>
    <tripID>75</tripID>
    <tripID>79</tripID>
    <tripID>85</tripID>
    <tripID>88</tripID>
</Trips>
```

and the output1.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TripsToPlan>
    <ids>75,79,85,88</ids>
    <numberofShifts>4</numberofShifts>
</TripsToPlan>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have a specific question or difficulty? Or are you just looking for someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: I'm trying to learn on my own, but I don't even know where to start. I just want to know what part of the code does what and how can I test it. As you can see, it looks very simple, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Start with any tutorial on XPath (e.g. https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3), then with any tutorial on XSLT https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an EXSLT extension to count, not sure if there is another way.

This XSLT applied to your source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exslt"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Trips"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Trips">
        <TripsToPlan>
            <ids>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="tripID"/> 
            </ids>
            <numberofShifts>
                <xsl:call-template name="countLines">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="tripID"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                
            </numberofShifts>
        </TripsToPlan>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tripID">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="countLines">
        <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(exslt:node-set($nodes))"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TripsToPlan>
   <ids>75,79,85,88</ids>
   <numberofShifts>4</numberofShifts>
</TripsToPlan>
```

Look through it, try to understand what happens, change it and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Excuse me for my noob question, but how can I test it? lol

Comment: what IDE are you using? I have "Oxygen XML editor". There is also "Altova", but these you have to pay for. there is an "Eclipse" plugin for XSLT, not sure if there is one for "IntelliJ Idea". Try those I would say.
There are online tools to do XSLT transformations but I would get an IDE to be honest.

Comment: Why all that complication of a named template, a parameter and then even the use of `exsl:node-set` if all you want is `<numberofShifts><xsl:value-of select="count(tripID)"/></numberofShifts>`?

Comment: nice Martin, you see, I like to make things complicated :-)